# Add_rewrite_rule in HivePress (WordPress plugin/theme)

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to change URL structure, to make it more SEO-friendly.
I use HivePress theme/plugin and there is a filter block? when you use it, the result gets URL for example like this

```
https://example.com/?_sort=&s=&post_type=hp_listing&_category=3&price%5B%5D=799&price%5B%5D=2599&old_price%5B%5D=999&old_price%5B%5D=3299
```

But I need it to change. I've tried to use add_rewrite_rule, but there is no any result.

For example,

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^_sort/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=_sort$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

or

```
function wpd_filter_rewrite() {

add_rewrite_rule(
    '^_sort/([^/]+)/?',
    'index.php?pagename=sort=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_filter_rewrite' );

Still have no idea...

Comment: Firstly, do you have pretty permalinks turned on? the `add_rewrite_rule` function only works for "pretty" permalinks (e.g. `/%postname%/`). If your site is using "ugly" permalinks (e.g. `/?p=236`), the rewrite rule will not work. In that case, you will need to use the add_rewrite_tag function. 

Also, in the `wpd_filter_rewrite()` function, The rewrite rule should use double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') to allow for variable interpolation

Comment: I've tried to follow your recommendations, but still.....no any result